# Polynomial and squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let f be the polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z[x]}$ defined by
$f(x)=x^4-22x^3+135x^2-154x-34$. How many times f(n) is a perfect square when $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ ?

This problem I solved another way than the short one user96233 did, gave the "occasion" to use congruences as with some easy Diophantine problems. Let me edit and reformulated it in order to prevent this does not happen:

**Problem**: How many times the expression in natural numbers

E(n) = $n^4-3n^3-8n^2+7n+127$

represents a perfect square?

Comment: I don't see any integral answers by graphing f(x) and y=x^2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write f(n)$\mod 4$ it will always be congruent to 2. Now, squares$\mod 4$ are either 0 or 1, so f(n) cannot be a square.

Comment: Applause.My answer "was" longer.